# Foreign keys and pivot tables using dapper extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper, dapper-extensions

I am using dapper extension methods like insert for everything related to the database in a project but I am not able to connect the models to each other. There are 4 tables in the database: category, event, speaker, and eventspeaker (pivot table). Is there a way to do it like using classmappings in NHibernate? Or do I have to change all foreign keys to int and do everything in the Save, update, etc.. methods?

```
public class Event
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public Category Category {get;set;}
  public string Location {get;set;}
  public DateTime Time {get;set;}

  public void Save(){ /*TODO*/}
 }      

public class Category
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Category {get;set;}
  public void Save(){ /*TODO*/}
 }      

public class Speaker
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public void Save(){ /*TODO*/}
 }      

public class EventSpeaker
{
  public Event event {get; set;}
  public Speaker Speaker {get;set;}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for pivot tables yet in DapperExtensions.

Foreign keys should be stored as integers. If say a category instance is required for each event, then a non-mapped category instance can also be added.

A class should also be added for each pivot table.